# Formatting big int SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, formatting

I have table with following data example table (`id int, sn bigint`)

```
id   sn
--------------------------
1    8921901414327625990
1    8921901414327625991
```

How can I remove the `892190` from `sn`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way, using modulo:

```
select sn % 10000000000000 from table1
```